# Connect to the Docker container from host network

Tags: windows, docker

I have a WcfService under .NET Framework, it is older server-side of application. I need to migrate it to the Windows Docker container on machine with Windows 10.

Beside that there will be running few IIS containers, that will interact with this WcfService but container to container communication is clear to me.

Then I have a client desktop application that must also be able to connect to the WcfService. In configuration file I specify Port and Hostname of wcfservice so I can connect.
This client may run on any machine within same LAN as WcfService container.

How should I construct command `docker run <params> wcfservice` and are there any other steps (firewall, Hyper-V settings,...) I need to do so that LAN can see this service and how can I retrieve hostname and port from this container?

Comment: If you map the ports to host then you can directly connect to localhost on that port. You can also run the container on host network and have them available on the network. What works better for you?

Comment: I think running container on host network would be the best, but I am using Windows container, so `docker network create host -d host` is not supported as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Comment: So just map the ports and access them from localhost: docker run -p <host_port>:<container_port> .... And then you should be able to for example: telnet localhost <host_port>